# What are the practices for a small multiplayer shooting game in node?

Tags: flash, node.js, multiplayer

I have a single player small game built in flash, which is similar to worms. You move your mouse to calculate an angle, click to shoot, and apply more or less power to your shot depending on the wind.

The physics for this are entirely programmed in actionscript. I was wondering what would be the best solution if I wanted to build a real time multiplayer 1 vs 1 version. For now I have setup a small example of flash and node on the backend communicating with sockets (net modules in node.js) passing data in json format. So far everything is ok. I have a specific issue that comes into mind right now though...

1) Should the bullet animations be handled by the client only, only the server, or both?

If the client handles all the bullet animation it's going to be easier to cheat, but easier to develop sinde it's already done. If the server handles it, I'm going to have to build functionality to smooth out the animations. But perhaps, since it's only a 1 vs 1 simple game which is going to be free and only for fun, should continue to move the bullets in flash, detect collisions in flash, and notify the server if I hit my opponent? Or is there something else I could do?

Answer (score 1):

Logic that could be exploited should be done on the server. Visualizations is logic that can't be exploited or even if so, it won't affect the other player. It should be done on the client.

Also when you receive data for every shot you should check if it is valid (whether the power is too big or whether the player has ran out of bullets for example). This is the kind of logic that can be exploited.

Also *Flash* supports *TCP Sockets*, so does *Node*. Instead of making a request/response architecture it is much more effective to use sockets.

One more advice, with technologies like [HTML5 Canvas](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/), [WebSockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) and [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) you should consider building your application in *HTML* and *JavaScript*, since that would enable all users on all devices to play it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using sockets, forgot to mention. I'm still not sure how I should sync the bullet animations though.

Comment: @Bastrix: Synchronize a begin timer between the two to compensate for animation latency delay. Then, when spawning a projectile, send the origin, direction, velocity and TIME. The client can then interpret where it should be at given point in time to update the visuals. Collisions still need to happen on the server.

Comment: Ok I will try synchronizing with the server every 100 milliseconds or so and updating the position in flash, see how that works out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually you don't need the two clients to be perfectly synchronized. A slight delay won't affect the gameplay. You'll start the animation as soon as you get data on the socket for the enemy shot.

Comment: isn't it just easier to detect collision in flash and notify to the server, and add functionality to avoid hacking?

Comment: @Bastrix "Avoiding hacking" is either going to not work, or you're going to end up running the simulation on the server to detect collisions.  Clients can send any data they want, regardless of your "anti-hacking" measures.

Comment: Mmmm ok, shouldn't be too difficult to do the calculations on the server then. Thanks for the help.